# Filtrar informações de uma CASE WHEN SQL e apenas resultados que contem todas as informações

Tags: sql, select, where, when

Preciso que me retornasse somente o resultado que contem todas as informações que no caso dessa imagem e o ID='8187'

```
Select d.ID, d.post_title, d.post_type,
MIN(CASE WHEN b.name = 'Resinas' THEN b.name END) AS categoria, 
MIN(CASE WHEN b.name = 'featured' THEN b.name END) AS destaque
from wp_term_taxonomy a
inner join wp_terms b on a.term_id = b.term_id
inner join wp_term_relationships c on a.term_taxonomy_id = c.term_taxonomy_id
inner join wp_posts d on c.object_id = d.id
where b.name IN ('Resinas', 'featured') and d.post_type = 'product'
GROUP BY d.ID
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: group by d.id HAVING ( MIN( ...) IS NOT NULL AND MIN(....) IS NOT NULL ) ajudaria se o sql fosse texto ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conseguir resolver da seguinte forma

```
Select *
FROM
(
Select d.ID, d.post_title, d.post_type,
MIN(CASE WHEN b.name = 'Resinas' THEN b.name END) AS categoria, 
MIN(CASE WHEN b.name = 'featured' THEN b.name END) AS destaque
from wp_term_taxonomy a
inner join wp_terms b on a.term_id = b.term_id
inner join wp_term_relationships c on a.term_taxonomy_id = c.term_taxonomy_id
inner join wp_posts d on c.object_id = d.id
where b.name IN ('Resinas', 'featured') and d.post_type = 'product'
GROUP BY d.ID
) AS x
WHERE x.destaque = 'featured' AND x.post_type = 'product' AND x.categoria = 'Resinas'
```